# How can I reduce the time to compile this solve?

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations, findinstance

I want to find five integer numbers $a, b, c, d, e$ so that $a+ b+ c  + d + e = 9 k$ and none of two number in which are equal. I tried.

```
    {a, b, c, d, e, k} /. 
 Solve[{a + b + c + d + e == 9 k, 0 <= a <= 9, 0 <= b <= 9, 
   0 <= c <= 9, 0 <= d <= 9, 0 <= e <= 9, 
   1 <= k <= 
    5, (a - b) (a - c) (a - d) (a - e) (b - c) (b - d) (b - e) (c - d) (c - e) (d - e) != 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, k}, Integers]
```

For a long time, I can not get the result. How can I get the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SolveValues[{a + b + c + d + e == 9 k, 0 <= a < b < c < d < e <= 9, 
  1 <= k <= 5}, {a, b, c, d, e, k}, Integers]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `1 <= k <= 5` constraint: `SolveValues[{a + b + c + d + e == 9 k, 
  0 <= a < b < c < d < e <= 9}, {a, b, c, d, e, k}, Integers]` will do just fine.

Comment: @Roman Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For versions prior to `v12.3` that don't feature the `SolveValues` command, you can use the `FindInstance` command. This will find `10` instances over the domain of `PositiveIntegers`.

```
FindInstance[
 a + b + c + d + e == 9 k && 1 <= k <= 5 && 
  UnsameQ[a, b, c, d, e], {a, b, c, d, e, k}, PositiveIntegers, 10]
```

> {{a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 28, k -> 4}, {a -> 6, b -> 30,
> c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 1, k -> 5}, {a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 4, d -> 13,
> e -> 23, k -> 5}, {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 2, e -> 18,    k ->
> 3}, {a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 1, e -> 9, k -> 2}, {a -> 5,    b ->
> 1, c -> 1, d -> 2, e -> 36, k -> 5}, {a -> 7, b -> 1, c -> 2,    d ->
> 13, e -> 22, k -> 5}, {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 2, d -> 37, e -> 2,    k
> -> 5}, {a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 20,    k -> 3}, {a -> 6, b -> 2, c -> 5, d -> 5, e -> 27, k -> 5}}

---

Essentially you want `IntegerPartitions` of `{9, 18, 27, 36, 45}` such that all integers in the set are unique. To get the complete list:

```
pall = (IntegerPartitions[9 #, {5}] & /@ Range[5]);
Pick[pall, Map[Apply[UnsameQ][#] &, pall, {2}]]
```

No luck with `9` as `1+2+3+4` would be `10`. You can get the same result with:

```
Pick[pall, Map[DuplicateFreeQ, pall, {2}]]
```